# Facebook Pixel content_ids as MongoDb ObjectID's?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, ads, next.js

I have a NextJs marketplace that requires Facebook Pixel integration, and a requirement for any Facebook Pixel event is content_ids (which can be one value), in all examples, it's a number value.
Is it possible to use MongoDb's ObjectID instead of a type number?

```
    ReactPixel.track('ViewContent', {
    content_name: product.name,
    content_category: product.category.name,
    content_ids: product._id,
    image_link: image,
    content_type: 'product',
    value: product.price,
    currency: 'USD',
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily answered by a look in the documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/reference#object-properties:

> **content_ids** - Array of *integers or strings* - Product IDs associated with the event, such as SKUs (e.g. `['ABC123', 'XYZ789']`).